# Position View on specified point of scaled ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, pixel

I've problem that I can't solve...

I've a custom imageview, that is changing it's size depending on what is bigger - width or height of layout that contains this view. It's working that way to always fit into layout.

```
public class AspectRatioImageView extends ImageView {

    public AspectRatioImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AspectRatioImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AspectRatioImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if (getDrawable() == null) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        } else {
            int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

            if (width > height) {           
                width = height * getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth() / getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
            } else
                height = width * getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth() / getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        setImageDrawable(null);

        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }
}
```

And it's putted in layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layMap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mFlipper"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layControl" >

    <com.mobiler.pogodynka.controls.AspectRatioImageView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ostrzezenia_hydro"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layMapOverlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/map"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/map"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/map"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/map"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that I've original map with size 1000x1000px. On this map I've some points. I have to show this map on Android and also add other Views on the same points like in the original map.

So for example:

- original map is 1000x1000px
- I'm getting screen width with this:

  public int getScreenWidth() {
      DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
      getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
      int wt = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
      return wt;
  }
- i.e. on nexus 4 I've got 800px
- getting the image from server and putting it into my custom imageview by setImageBitmap().
- then I'm translating original point on map to new, scaled one; for i.e. on orignal map I'd have point x = 408, y = 68. On scaled map it would be 326, 54. My View that i want to put on map is 36x36 pixels.

Unfortunatelly here comes the problem...
 - first - my original location is center of point, but for View I can only set top and left offset. If I subtract its half of size - I'd get new center point for my View.
 - second - there comes density... How on earth can i position this thing on different screens? I was wondering if this would work:

```
public int getPositionX(int imageWidth) {
    Resources resources = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    int position = (int) ((imageWidth * (X - metrics.density * 20)) / 1000);
    return position;
}
```

I've checked it on NExus 4 and 7 and it works. But on other devices - not, the new points are misplaced... And this "20" is sth I'am not sure. I was first thinking that there shouold be half of image size but not - if i put "18"then it's going to be missaligned...

Here is how it look like:
 - how it should look - http://imageshack.com/a/img560/9417/6mz8.png
 - how it shouldn't - http://imageshack.com/a/img24/2822/2u6p.png

Could someone help me solve this?

Comment: see how im doing that here https://github.com/pskink/PatchworkDrawable

Comment: Thanks for this but your approach was too much for what i wanted to achieve :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it. It looks like my approach was good.

To offset an ImageView by proper value of pixels I just need to multiply half (to get the center) of its width/height and subract it from original scaled position.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
final int offset = (int) (36/2 * metrics.density);
```

And then setting the correct offset:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(marker.getPositionX(mMap.getWidth()) - offset,
marker.getPositionY(mMap.getHeight()) - offset, 0, 0);          
point.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Where getPosition scales position based on 1000px map to real device size:

```
public int getPositionX(int imageWidth) {
    int position = (int) ((imageWidth * X) / 1000);
    return position;
}
```

Comment: why that mega complex math? what you really need is: 1) getImageMatrix(), 2) invert it by calling  inverse, 3) call mapPoints or mapRect on inverted matrix

Comment: Well, for me it's simple as 2+2... And I really don't get the idea of using Matrix. Maybe if you have some time, could you explain it? As I understand it, mapPoints would give me the same what is giving me now the getPositionX method?

Comment: your 2+2 will work only for specific data (for example tour ImageView has to have the same aspect ratio as the Drawable is shows), if your map has dims 1010x990 all your math is failing, with Matrix you can use normal ImageView and scale your Drawable as you wish and Matrix mapping will always be fine since it is that Matrix that tranforms the Canvas in order to draw your Drawable with any scaleType you want

Comment: Yes, you're right that it will work only on specific conditions. For project I'm using it - they will be always true. I'll try to dig dipper into using Matrix, as it could be helpful in future. Thanks!